# kafka messages monitoring to show the actual messages published or consumed

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have `kafka` installed on my local server, and through some other application running in the server produers are publishing messages to the brokers inside of my `kafka` server, through the `zookeeper` I can easily see the health of my `kafka` which shows all the topics created inside my `kafka` server a, offsets inside topics etc etc, so only thing `zookeeper` is not able to show is the messages that are inside the individual topics, so someone recommended `kafka-manager` tool, I installed and ran it, it worked fine, it showed lot of information from my `kafka` server, but still it was not able to show real messages that are published or consumed by respective consumers inside my `kafka` server, so my question is , is there a way/tool/code to find out the messages published or consumed, I mean in addition to this `kafka-manager` or I have Install some plugins inside of the same `kafka-manager` so that it will also show the respective messages.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh`

Answer (score 1):

A Kafka broker cannot tell you how many messages are have been consumed for a given consumer on a given topic. The only thing that a Kafka broker knows about is the current log offset of the consumer, and the current max offset of the log. It cannot however, tell you how many messages before the current offset the consumer actually received, as it keeps no counters around this, and the consumer defines its own initial position (as well as being able to seek to various places in the log).

You can get both of these numbers using the `$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh` script.